# Pensions of British EU Civil Service in Theresa May's brexit deal

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, pensions

Back in 2016, there was disagreement over who would foot the bill for pensions paid out to British members of [EU Civil Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Civil_Service). Normally, they would get their pensions from the EU, but due to brexit the EU had (in 2016) taken the following position ([according to the telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/08/02/eu-demands-britain-pays-pensions-of-1730-eurocrats-in-wake-of-br/)):

> But EU officials say Britain would be expected to pay its part of the EU's pension promises when it finally quits the EU.

[The article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2016/08/02/eu-demands-britain-pays-pensions-of-1730-eurocrats-in-wake-of-br/) goes on to state:

> According to some senior EU officials one compromise could involve the UK paying a lump sum to close its exposure and create a standalone pension fund.

How does Theresa May's brexit deal handle these pensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing there that I can find that is specific to British members of the EU Civil Service.

What I do see, in [Article 142, Paragraph 6](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=OJ:C:2019:066I:FULL#ntr142-CI2019066EN.01000101-E0144), is a provision to be made for the UK to pay a share of pension benefits to all EU civil servants.

> For the pensions referred to in the first subparagraph, the payment by the United Kingdom shall be
>   the sum of the net payments made by the Union budget in the preceding year for each beneficiary,
>   multiplied by the United Kingdom's share and by a percentage that is specific to each beneficiary
>   ("specific percentage").

Answer (score 2):

The deal that Theresa May negotiated with the EU and that the UK parliament rejected contained a major payment made by the UK to the EU (about £35-£40 billion) which would pay for all legal obligations of the UK to the EU, and with that payment made, the EU would pay for all those pensions.

If there is a no deal Brexit, and no payment made by the UK to cover its obligations, nobody knows, but it wouldn't make sense for the EU to pay in this situation. I would hope that the UK would pay.

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense for the EU to pay? The work was done for that organization.